# как распарсить этот JSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "data": [{
        "id": "6",
        "title": "something",
        "body": "something",
        "created": 1467451711,
        "author": {
            "name": "something",
            "logo": "something.png"
        },
        "images": [{
            "src": "something.jpg",
            "created": "2016-07-02 09:28:31"
        }],
        "likes": 9,
        "width": 100
    }, {
        "id": "5",
        "title": "something",
        "body": "something",
        "created": 1467226414,
        "author": {
            "name": "something",
            "logo": "something.png"
        },
        "images": [{
            "src": "something.jpg",
            "created": "2016-06-29 18:53:34"
        }, {
            "src": "something.jpg",
            "created": "2016-06-29 18:53:35"
        }, {
            "src": "something.jpg",
            "created": "2016-06-29 18:53:35"
        }],
        "likes": 12,
        "width": 33
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "something",
        "body": "something",
        "created": 1467180754,
        "author": {
            "name": "something",
            "logo": "something.png"
        },
        "likes": 13,
        "width": 0
    }]
}
```

помогите это распарсить пожалуйста
вроде все правильно делаю

```
for (int i = 0; i < data_obj.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = data_obj.getJSONObject(i);
                            JSONObject b=c.getJSONObject("author");
                            name1 = b.getString("name");
                            logo1 = b.getString("logo");
                            id = c.getString("id");
                            title = c.getString("title");
                            body = c.getString("body");
                            created = c.getString("created");
                            likes = c.getString("likes");
                            width = c.getString("width");

                        }
```

Comment: А в чём, собственно, у Вас проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это ленивыми делается так:

1. Берём либу Gson
2. Пользуем сайт типа [этого](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) для преобразования JSON в Java классы.
3. Парсим JSON в Java классы либой из п.1 примерно так:

```
String jsonString = ...;
Example result = new Gson.Builder().build().fromJson(jsonString, Example.class);
```

В итоге вся инфа у вас будет в переменной result и к ней легко и просто обращаться.

---

Полученные с сайта классы

-----------------------------------com.example.Author.java-----------------------------------

```
package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Author {

@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
public String name;
@SerializedName("logo")
@Expose
public String logo;

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Datum.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Datum {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
public String id;
@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
public String title;
@SerializedName("body")
@Expose
public String body;
@SerializedName("created")
@Expose
public int created;
@SerializedName("author")
@Expose
public Author author;
@SerializedName("images")
@Expose
public List<Image> images = null;
@SerializedName("likes")
@Expose
public int likes;
@SerializedName("width")
@Expose
public int width;

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Example.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
public String status;
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
public List<Datum> data = null;

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Image.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Image {

@SerializedName("src")
@Expose
public String src;
@SerializedName("created")
@Expose
public String created;

}
```

Comment: не могу понять что делать в  3 пункте можете скинуть какую нибудь рабочую версию для примера